# Pandas найти подстроку не учитывая регистр

Tags: python, pandas

подскажите. Есть df, в нем столбец stolbec. Подскажите как реализвать поиск подстроки в столбце без восприимчивости к регистру.  Обычный find не работает. (вроде)

Comment: Можно просто привести все строки к одному регистру: `your_string = your_string.lower()`.

Comment: А если не хочется изменять данные? может там абривиатуры капсом или имена собсвтенные, по которым кроме заглавное не понятно? И не получается применить этот метод для столцба в df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерный датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(['aa', 'Aa', 'AA', 'bb', 'c','foaaa'], columns=['stolbec'])
```

Имеем:

```
  stolbec
0      aa
1      Aa
2      AA
3      bb
4       c
5   foaaa
```

выводим то, что нам нужно:

```
mystring = 'aa'
df[df['stolbec'].str.contains(mystring, case=False)]
```

Итог:

```
    stolbec
0   aa
1   Aa
2   AA
5   foaaa
```